# Accessing os files with django inside an electron application

Tags: reactjs, django, electron

I have a web application built with Django/React. I want to convert it to an electron app and am unsure if I need to refactor some of the backend code to node.js.

Here is the relevant information:

1. User needs to create a file with their own API token received from 3rd party. I would like to avoid sending their personal token to my server and want to keep it on their operating system.
2. Django uses the token to query data from the 3rd party api.
3. Django sends data back to front end.

My question is, once the application is bundled as an electron app, can django access their api token and query the 3rd party api without hitting my server? Will the django code be run on the localhost (or can it) is I guess what I mean.

Thanks, hope this is a valid SO question.

Comment: So you're having a Django application that runs on your own server, but you also want to have a desktop application going with it, right? Why are you thinking of bundling the whole Django application with the Electron app? Couldn't Electron just be the frontend and contact your backend server via HTTPS? That way, you would read/write files from within your Electron app. Also, bringing a whole HTTP server to your client's PCs seems an awful lot like unnecessary bloat.

Comment: Part of the 3rd party API license is that you can't share your key, I'm assuming that means with my server as well. Although most of the other django code will live on my own server, the portion of the code that deals with the data processing of the 3rd party data, I was planning on bundling to avoid a refactor. But after thinking about it a refactor would avoid having to bundle python at all, so maybe writing it all in javascript would be the best solution. Thanks for your reply.